# Sync Services Ado.net define Range Id

Tags: ado.net, resolution, conflict, syncservices

is there a way to define a range of id's for insertions in a table in a client DB, using Sync Services for ado.net? does Sync services have any predicted support for such a case?
tks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Sync Services will ever provide such a feature. If you need to do that, you have to override/provide your own insert commands to the sync provider.